# C error: term does not evaluate to function taking n arguments (C2064)

Tags: c

I'm working on a simple model of blood glucose based on a set of equations:

u1 = 200e^–2(t – 2) for 2.0 <= t < 5.0

u1 = 200e^–2(t – 8) for 8.0 <= t < 11.0

u1 = 200e^–2(t – 16) for 16.0 <= t < 19.0

u1 = 0 otherwise

So I wrote my slope function as

```
float slope1(float t, float g, float s) {
    float out1;
    float u1 = 0;
    for (t = 0; t <= 24; t++) {
        if (2.0 <= t < 5.0) {
            u1 = 200 * exp(-2(t - 2));
        }
        else if (8.0 <= t < 11.0) {
            u1 = 200 * exp(-2(t - 8));
        }
        else if (16.0 <= t < 19.0) {
            u1 = 200 * exp(-2(t - 16));
        }
        else {
            u1 == 0;
        }
    }
    if (g <= 90) {
        out1 = u1 - (0.05 * g * s) + ((1.0 * 100) - (1.0 * g)) - 10;
    }
    else if (g > 90) {
        out1 = u1 - (0.05 * g * s) - 10;
    }
    return out1;
}
```

But I am getting the error message "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments". The error is in each line that evaluates u1 (all three of the u1 = 200*x ones). What does this error mean, and how I should go about solving it?

Comment: 1. This is not “error handling”. 2. Your compiler will tell you exactly _where_ it found an error, but you don’t tell us. 3. Comparisons don’t work like that. 4. Your formula is really, really strange. 5. Use double unless you can explain why float is better in your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to posting and misunderstood the tags. The errors are in the lines with the exp function (at each u1= line). I'm not sure what you mean by "comparisons don't work like that", or what you mean by my formula being strange. I'm also unsure how to use double properly or where/why. Thanks for your help, sorry for the dumb questions.

Comment: The compiler thinks this should be a function call: `-2(t - 8)` but `2` is not a function taking 1 parameter as the compiler tells you. If that should not be a function call, you need to add some operand. There is no implicit multiplication assumed if you just put some symbols together without any operand in between.

Comment: Oh my gosh, what a simple mistake. I've been wrestling with this for almost no reason. Thank you so much, Gerhardh!

Comment: Computer programs must follow the rules of their language. You can't just take stuff written in some other language (like mathematics) and expect it to match the computer program language. Just like you can't take a sentence in French and paste it into an English essay.